# Paypal button creation for another account

Tags: button, paypal

I need to create Paypal button for someone else's account.  My client has given me their API username, password and signature.  I need to create a button for them but I think in order to do that, I need access to their merchant account, based on the info they gave me.

Is it possible to create the button for them with the information they have provided or will they need to make the button in their merchant account and send me the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a button for them by going to www.paypal.com/buttonfactory and all you will need is the email address they have associated with their PayPal account to link the button to their account.

Comment: Looks like they only let you choose from your own registered email addresses now